# Robo 3T error No unix socket support on windows

Tags: windows-10, connection, database, cloud, mongodb

I'm trying to connect my cloud database from mongodb atlas to robo 3t. I created a database and entered the connection string and it tells me it connected to my connection string but the next step fails and it says "Failed to load list of databases" when I clicked Show error details it gives me the error "Cannot connect to MongoDB at [...]:27017" and "Error: No unix socket support on windows."

Comment: What version of Robo 3T are you using? Robo 3T embeds a specific version of the `mongo` shell so you may have compatibility issues, especially if you are using an older version. I believe older versions will report this error if you include a "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://" prefix in your connection string. Robo 3T 1.3 (released April 3, 2019) uses the 4.0 shell and should resolve this issue.